# Setting up AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, android-studio

I added `AndEngine` as a module dependency but when I try to run my project I am faced with the following error :

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Game:compileDebug'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

And

```
Gradle: error: package org.andengine.engine.camera does not exist
```

Has anyone been able to successfully get their `AndEngine` running on Android Studio? I would greatly appreciate it if you could tell me the steps I need to take to get it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating the project in `eclipse` and setting up andengine for the project, then importing that same project in `android studio`, set up the required dependencies then I been using it since no hassle.